# Obtaining information about Facebook user access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've read many posts about this, but what I'm doing still doesn't seem to be working.

I want to obtain information about a user access token that has (at some point) been authorized for my app. I use the documented call:

```
/debug_token?
input_token={input-token}&amp;
access_token={access-token}
```

In making this call, I have tried replacing the access-token placeholder with {appID}|{app-secret}.

I have also obtained an app access token using

```
/oauth/access_token
?client_id={app-id}
&client_secret={app-secret}
&grant_type=client_credentials
```

I then used the returned access_token to replace the access-token placeholder.

In both cases, I get "The App_id in the input_token did not match the Viewing App."

This is confusing to begin with, because the input-token placeholder does not *have* an App_id. That placeholder is supposed to contain the access token about which you wish to obtain information.

In the instance where I generated an app access token, the call using it was made immediately afterward.

Facebook documentation being a combination of specific and opaque, could someone please suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Just because the token does not contain what you can visibly identify as an app id, does not mean it is not tied to an app id internally. And the app id of the token you want to inspect, and the app access token you supply to authorize the request, must match, which according to the error message is not the case here. (Just to be sure, you replaced `&amp;` with a simple `&`?)

Comment: Thanks for your response. First, yes, I used a simple &. I understand your point about a token being tied to an app id internally.But your second comment, about the "match," I don't understand. 

The tokens I used for the input-token value were tokens previously returned from authorizations obtained by our clients to authorize our app to access their accounts. Thus the token may have expired, but it was authorized for use by our app previously. The access_token value was a generated app-access token or the combination of the app's ID and secret key. In this instance, what needed to match?

Comment: The token you want to debug and the access token must belong to the same app, and according to the error message, they don’t. Please take the token and debug it here, that will show you what app it belongs to: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: Thanks. I understand. However, I've used the tool, and it identifies our AppID correctly. And now, the precise same calls to the debug-token API are returning different results: the correct information structure. No code has changed, No access tokens changed. Just the results. So thanks for your response. But it now appears it wasn't me; it was Facebook.